# Does Javascript Remoting Count Towards API Limits?

Tags: governorlimits, javascript-remoting

As the title says, do Javascript remoting calls count towards API limits?

I know that calls to an Apex REST API count towards them, but I don't know if this is the same for remoting calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, JavaScrpit remoting does not constitute an API call.

Comment: Any chance of a reference? Or do you know this from experiementation?

Comment: @LaceySnr there are few links in this [IDEA](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000iJHLAA2) which talks about JavaScript remoting not counted towards API Limits.

Comment: I've also tested this in the past: `apex:actionFunction`, `apex:actionPoller`, and `@RemoteAction` calls are free. `executeAnonymous` calls cost the normal rate, obviously.

Comment: I have been running some javascript remoting in my sandbox and it does seem to be increasing the api usage count? Do you know if it actually does count or not